# gral-examples Maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I added gral-core Maven dependency to my project as it is explained here
http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Download

Problem is that I also need to add gral-examples.jar in Maven dependencies, but I cannot find the code for it. I need this to work because I share this project with few other people via EGit plugin for Eclipse, so I can't just add this library to build path, I need it to be Maven dependency.

Comment: Why, they have this jar published in repository. See last paragraph for the article you link

Comment: they have  <artifactId>gral-core</artifactId> and I need it to be  <artifactId>gral-examples</artifactId>, but there is no such dependency on that site.

Comment: The problem was about versions. gral-core has 0.10 latest version, but gral-examples only 0.9, so I was making mistake by adding gral-examples 0.10 dependency instead of 0.9